# Zoom In zoom out d3 js loaded svg file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I loaded an svg file in my div using d3 js using following function:

```
d3.xml(mapUrl, "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
    document.getElementById("floorCanvas").appendChild(xml.documentElement);
  });
```

Here `mapUrl` is the variable containing the path of svg file.

I want to add zoom in zoom out feature to this svg file.

I tried zooming the parent div but no luck.

Please help.

Comment: try this,  https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom

Comment: can you please add a fiddle.

Comment: I have also created an interactive map out of SVGs: http://arda-maps.org/ maybe you get some ideas about how to do the zooming from there. Otherwhise just ask =)